# How big a matrix can we row reduce in reasonable time?

Tags: matrix, linear-solver

I have very large matrices that I would like to row reduce (I need to keep track of the steps and find a basis of the kernel/image, not just find the rank).

The good news is that I work mod 2 and the matrices are very sparse. The problem is their size, right now I have a beast that is roughly 3 millions x 1 million, but I expect much bigger, probably billions. I might have a thousand of those matrices that I would like to reduce eventually.

I found the linbox project that might be helpful, but before I wanted to know if anybody has a feeling whether or not this is realistic ? I could be using the Grid of my university which has "the combined processing power of 4,568 cores: 1,346 Intel cores, 3,222 AMD cores, with over 13.5TB of RAM and 1.2PB of disk space.". What do you think ?

Thanks!

Comment: from what I know of linbox, this seems to be extremely large and probably not realistic.  I'd suggest that you contact the authors of linbox and ask them their opinion.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, I saw there is even a google forum for asking them questions.

Comment: How sparse are they? The sparsity pattern changes during row reduction, so efficient representation of the matrix in memory is really important.

Comment: I believe that Sage uses linbox to do row reductions over GF(2), so you might find try using Sage to get a sense of what size problems it can handle and how much fill-in you're likely to see for your problems.

Comment: These kinds of problems (row reductions over GF(2)) are the final phase of [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) factorization schemes, though it sounds like you really are shooting for about twice as many columns as were needed for the record QS factorization.

Comment: "I work mod 2" means the content are just 0 and 1? Then the row reduction operations are just XOR (and swap), right? To harness the binary nature, I guess you should try to find a tool that specifically does that, not just a general solver.